# Spring batch read file one by one. File content is not constant

Tags: spring, spring-batch

MultiResourceItemReader reads all files sequentially.

I want once one file read completely, it should call processor/writer.it should not read next file.

Since file content is not constant, i can't go with chunk size.

Any idea on chunk policy to decide end of file content?

Comment: Batch processing is about fixed datasets (and in Spring Batch, this is required for restartability). If your file keeps growing, a streaming solution is more appropriate for you.

Comment: Hi, I am able to write custom file reader class and able to read complete file one by one. Do you find any issue here.

Comment: Using MultiResourceItemReader, assigning multiple file reasources.
Using custom file reader as delegate, reading a file completely 
For reading file completely, come up with a logic

Comment: Hi Ben, I have updated the code below. Please post your comment on this

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a step which read/process/write only one file with a "single file item reader" (like FlatFileItemReader). And repeat the step while there are files remainig.

Spring batch gives you a feature to do so : [conditional flows](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#conditionalFlow) and in particular the [programmatic flow decision](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#programmaticFlowDecisions) which gives you a smart way to decide when to stop a loop between steps (when there is not file any more)

And since you will not be able to give a constant input file name to your reader, you should also have a look at [Late binding section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#late-binding).

Hope this will be enough to help you. Please, make comments if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
Using MultiResourceItemReader, assigning multiple file reasources.
Using custom file reader as delegate, reading a file completely 
For reading file completely, come up with a logic


@Bean
    public MultiResourceItemReader<SimpleFileBean> simpleReader() 
    {
        Resource[]  resourceList  = getFileResources();
        
        if(resourceList == null) {
            System.out.println("No input files available");
        }
        
        MultiResourceItemReader<SimpleFileBean> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<SimpleFileBean>();
        resourceItemReader.setResources(resourceList);
        resourceItemReader.setDelegate(simpleFileReader());
        return resourceItemReader;
    }


    @Bean
    SimpleInboundReader simpleFileReader() {
        
        return new SimpleInboundReader(customSimpleFileReader());
    }

    @Bean 
    public FlatFileItemReader customSimpleFileReader() {    
    
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder()            
                .name("customFileItemReader")            
                .lineMapper(new PassThroughLineMapper())            
                .build(); 
        }


    public class SimpleInboundReader implements ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream{

    private Object currentItem = null;
    private FileModel fileModel = null;
    private String fileName = null;
    private boolean fileRead = false;
    
    
    
    private ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<String> delegate;
    
    public SimpleInboundReader(ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<String> delegate) {        
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {

        delegate.open(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.update(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        fileName = resource.getFilename();
        this.delegate.setResource(resource);
    }
    

    
    String getNextLine() throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException, Exception {
        
        return delegate.read();
    }


        @Override
    public SimpleFileBean read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        
        SimpleFileBean simpleFileBean = null;
    
        String currentLine = null;
        
        currentLine=delegate.read();
        
        if(currentLine != null) {
            
            simpleFileBean = new SimpleFileBean();
            simpleFileBean.getLines().add(currentLine);
            
            while ((currentLine  = getNextLine()) != null) {
                simpleFileBean.getLines().add(currentLine);
            }
            
            return simpleFileBean;
        }
      return null;
     }
  }
```